# Linear Model error or data type error?

Tags: r

The program generates a matrix with location and treatment. I generates some data from a normal distribution. It then tries to fit a linear model predicting yield based on treatment and location. The linear model does not work. Why?

```
trts = paste(0:6)
locs = paste(1:6)
reps = paste(1:4)
plotsize = 4
DF = expand.grid(locs, reps, trts, plotsize, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
colnames(DF) = c("Location","Replicate","Treatment")
vector = rnorm(1000000, mean=138.2, sd=54.89)
DF$Treatment = as.numeric(DF$Treatment)
DF$Location = as.numeric(DF$Location)
#This approach takes one set of "plotsize" values from "vector" and adds for 5 for each treatment.
DF$Yield = apply(DF, 1, function(x) (5*DF$Treatment)+mean(sample vector,plotsize)))
DF<-t(DF)
Yield<-DF$Yield
trt=as.factor(DF$Treatment)
loc=as.factor(DF$Location)
summary(fm1 <- aov(Yield ~ loc*trt))
result1<-TukeyHSD(fm1, "trtm", ordered = TRUE)
```

Comment: Your code does not work, breaking at `mean(sample vector,plotsize)`. What are you intending to do there?

Comment: I want it to go to "vector" withdraw "plotsize" number of samples, find the mean, and return it to "DF$Yield". If treatment=0 that is all it will do. For treatment=1 it will add five points to this mean. For treatment=2 it will add 10 points to this mean. And so forth. Ultimately, it will be necessary to get a new set of draws form "vector" for each "treatment."